# NLS setting in sql developer to change the Number format

Tags: sql, oracle, numbers

When i am trying to insert decimal value in KPI_FREQUENCY field which is Number datatype in oracle sql developer, its always inserting with ',' which is incorrect. I try to change NLS setting of decimal to '.' but still its inserting with','. I also tried to_char to insert the value with '.' but its not working.

```
Insert into RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION 
  (KPI_DEF_ID,KPI_NAME,KPI_DESC,KPI_FREQUENCY) 
values 
  ('10003881','Backlog Resul11t','Backlog Result11', 0.5);
```

Comment: The value inserted correctly I'm sure.  It's just when you try to display it, it gets formatted with a comma `,`.  How did you try to change the NLS setting?

Comment: If i go to tool->Preferences->Database-> NLS ->Decimal Separator to .

Comment: In that same config page, you have a setting for `Group Separator`.  Is that also set to a period `.`?  If so, change it to a comma `,` so that it doesn't conflict with your new decimal separator setting.

Comment: Now it works thanks :).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer to make it official:

In SQL Developer, `Preferences->Database-> NLS`, if you change the `Decimal Separator` setting, you also need to make sure that your new setting doesn't conflict with the existing `Group Separator` setting.

In this case, you needed to change `Decimal Separator` to a period `.`, but *also* change the `Group Separator` setting from a period to a comma `,` to avoid a setting conflict.